# For what values of $k>0$ does $abc=1 \implies \sum_{\mbox{cyc}}\left(\frac1{a+k}-\frac{a}{a^2+k}\right) \geq 0$?

Tags: inequality, substitution, buffalo-way

For what values of $k>0$ does $$abc=1 \implies \left(\frac1{a+k}-\frac{a}{a^2+k}\right) + \left(\frac1{b+k}-\frac{b}{b^2+k}\right)+
\left(\frac1{c+k}-\frac{c}{c^2+k}\right)\geq 0$$

This question arose while I was trying to find a proof of [For $abc=1$ prove that $\sum\limits_\text{cyc}\frac{1}{a+3}\geq\sum\limits_\text{cyc}\frac{a}{a^2+3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090810/for-abc-1-prove-that-sum-limits-textcyc-frac1a3-geq-sum-limits-text)

The observation is that for general $k>0$, when $a=b=c=1$, 
$f(a,b,c;k) \equiv \sum_{\mbox{cyc}}\left(\frac1{a+k}-\frac{a}{a^2+k}\right)=0$,
and that the 
minimum of $f(a,b,c=\frac1{ab};k)$ occurs at a point where at least two of the three variables $a,b,c$ are equal.

However, it is not in general true that $abc=1 \implies f(a,b,c;k)\geq 0$. For example, 
$$
f(2,2,\frac14;k=5) = -\frac{10}{567}
$$
Numerical experimentation tells me that for $\,0<k<4.1649638575$,
$abc=1 \implies f(a,b,c;k)\geq 0$, but that for $k>4.1649638575$, there is always some value of $a > 1.69$ such that 
$$
f(a,a,\frac1{a^2};k) < 0
$$

How would we prove these inequalities (even the $k=3$ case is proving to be quite difficult, yet I "know" that the $k=4$ case is also true)?

And does anybody recognize that upper bound $k>4.1649638575$ such that the implication holds for $k$ below that boundary?

Comment: It seems that for $k=4$ the inequality is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof for $k=4$.

Let $a=\frac{y}{x}$, $b=\frac{z}{y}$ and $c=\frac{x}{z}$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{4x+y}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{4x^2+y^2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^3-x^2y}{(4x+y)(4x^2+y^2)}\geq0.$$
Now, let $x=\min\{x,y,z\}$, $y=x+u$ and $z=x+v$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$125(u^2-uv+v^2)x^7+25(10u^3+29u^2v-24uv^2+10v^3)x^6+$$
$$+25(14u^4+55u^3v+27u^2v^2-51uv^3+14v^4)x^5+$$
$$+(225u^5+1279u^4v+1917u^3v^2-842u^2v^3-654uv^4+225v^5)x^4+$$
$$+(25u^6+679u^5v+1560u^4v^2+426u^3v^3-786u^2v^4+71uv^5+25v^6)x^3+$$
$$+uv(76u^5+740u^4v+512u^3v^2-286u^2v^3+59uv^4-v^5)x^2+$$
$$+u^2v^2(84u^4+264u^3v-92u^2v^2+37uv^3+7v^4)x+$$
$$+u^3v^3(32u^3-12u^2v+4uv^2+v^3)\geq0$$
and since $v^6x^3-uv^6x^2+u^2v^6x\geq0$, it remains to prove that:
$$125(u^2-uv+v^2)x^7+25(10u^3+29u^2v-24uv^2+10v^3)x^6+$$
$$+25(14u^4+55u^3v+27u^2v^2-51uv^3+14v^4)x^5+$$
$$+(225u^5+1279u^4v+1917u^3v^2-842u^2v^3-654uv^4+225v^5)x^4+$$
$$+(25u^6+679u^5v+1560u^4v^2+426u^3v^3-786u^2v^4+71uv^5+24v^6)x^3+$$
$$+uv(76u^5+740u^4v+512u^3v^2-286u^2v^3+59uv^4)x^2+$$
$$+u^2v^2(84u^4+264u^3v-92u^2v^2+37uv^3+6v^4)x+$$
$$+u^3v^3(32u^3-12u^2v+4uv^2+v^3)\geq0.$$
Let $x=\sqrt{uv}t$.

Hence, 
$$125(u^2-uv+v^2)x^7+25(10u^3+29u^2v-24uv^2+10v^3)x^6+$$
$$+25(14u^4+55u^3v+27u^2v^2-51uv^3+14v^4)x^5+$$
$$+(225u^5+1279u^4v+1917u^3v^2-842u^2v^3-654uv^4+225v^5)x^4+$$
$$+(25u^6+679u^5v+1560u^4v^2+426u^3v^3-786u^2v^4+71uv^5+24v^6)x^3+$$
$$+uv(76u^5+740u^4v+512u^3v^2-286u^2v^3+59uv^4)x^2+$$
$$+u^2v^2(84u^4+264u^3v-92u^2v^2+37uv^3+6v^4)x+$$
$$+u^3v^3(32u^3-12u^2v+4uv^2+v^3)\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{u^9v^9}(125t^7+440t^6+257t^5-136t^4-52t^3+241t^2+155t+10)\geq0,$$
where the last inequality is obviously true.

Done!

Comment: I just finished following your proof, and it is correct.  I'm giving this a check, because I don't think anybody is going to come up with a closed form (or form as a solution of a polynomial equation) for the upper bound on $k$.

Comment: I tried this method, using a tighter expression for the necessary subtraction, on $k=\frac{29}{7}$, which is still in the range where the minimum comes at $a=b=c=1$. If that worked, I was going to try $k=\frac{25}6$ which is out of that range, to see what stops working. But at $k=\frac{29}7$  this method  failed to prove the inequality. The subtraction used was $\frac{85}{98}v^6 x(x-u)^2$ and the last inequality became $\sqrt{u^9v^9} (116.59t^7+347.19t^6-82t^5-554.55t^4-305.44t^3+186.69t^2+161.93t+10.95 \geq 0$, which does not hold near $t=1$.

Comment: @Mark Fischler Yes of course! This method not always helps.