# how to continue after this substitution?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Given $abc=1$, prove that $${\frac{a}{a^2+2}}+ {\frac{b}{b^2+2}}+{\frac{c}{c^2+2}} \leqslant 1 $$

I tried substitution  $a={\frac{1}{x}},b={\frac{1}{y}},c={\frac{1}{z}}$ but can't finish.

Comment: I suspect that https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2090810/86846 will have some similar features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=\frac{x}{y},b=\frac{y}{z},c=\frac{z}{x}$ we have to prove

> $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{x^2+2y^2}\le 1$$ Now as $x^2+y^2\ge 2xy$ it suffices to prove

> $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{2x+y}\le 1 $$ $$\iff \sum_{cyc} \frac{y}{2x+y}\ge 1$$ which is true as

> $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{y}{2x+y}= \sum_{cyc} \frac{y^2}{2xy+y^2}\ge \frac{{(x+y+z)}^2}{2xy+y^2+2zx+x^2+2yz+z^2}=1$$

Comment: Nice!! ... [+1]

Comment: @Dr.Mathva thank you!

Comment: @Dr.Mathva if you have time please checkout this problem ,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4022005/proving-sum-cyc-fracaa22bcbc-ge-fracabc22    You may come up with an ingeniuos proof as you did before in another question of mine

Comment: Hmm, I've been trying it for a while, but it seems to be strong. CS and Jensen have both failed...

Comment: How did you get that one sum is less than one which is equivalent to a different sum larger than one?

Comment: @gournge  as $$\frac{x}{x+2y}=1-\frac{2y}{x+2y}$$

Comment: Is this good ? $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{a^2+2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a(a+2bc)}= \sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+2bc} $$ using AM-GM : $$a+2bc \geq 2\sqrt{2}$$ so $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+2bc} \le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\le 1$$ i dont know where but I’m sure that there is some mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Yassir RHS should be $\frac{3}{2\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Yeah you’re right i missed this .